# error Datable id=example can't reinitialize data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, razor-pages

I work on razor page asp.net core . I face  error Datable id=example can't reinitialize data table ?

so How to solve this error please ?

error happen when change select option printer server

I need when change select on select option printer server then hide or remove table with pagination option `first ,next,previous,last etc`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
     
            
           
        
            $('#PrintServer-select').change(function () {
                var printserverId = $(this).val();
               
                if (printserverId) {
                    console.log(printserverId);
                    $.ajax({
         
                        url: '?handler=RelatedBranches',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",

                        data: { printserverId: printserverId },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#branch-select').empty();
                            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                //console.log(item);
                                $('#branch-select').append($('<option>', {
                                    
                                    value: item.branchId,
                                    text: item.vBranchDesc
                                    
                                    
                                }));
                            });
                   
                            var tableShows = $('#example').DataTable({
                                paging: false
                            });

                            // Hide the table using jQuery
                            $('#example').hide();
                  
                            $('#example').DataTable();
                            if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
                                $('#example').destory();
                                // The DataTables instance is already initialized
                            } else {
                                // Initialize the DataTables plugin
                                $('#example').DataTable();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            
           
            var table = $("#example").dataTable({
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "paging": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                
                "columnDefs": [
                    { className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10", "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
                ],
                "lengthMenu": [[5,10, 15,20, 25, 35, 50, 100, -1], [5,10, 15,20, 25, 35, 50, 100, "All"]],
                "pageLength": 10 // Set the default page length to 10
            });
        
            

           
           
            table.destroy();

            
          
         
         

          

        });
    </script>
```

error happen on block below

```
 var tableShows = $('#example').DataTable({
                                    paging: false
                                });
    
                                // Hide the table using jQuery
                                $('#example').hide();
                     
                                $('#example').DataTable();
                                if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
                                    $('#example').destory();
                                    // The DataTables instance is already initialized
                                } else {
                                    // Initialize the DataTables plugin
                                    $('#example').DataTable();
                                }
```

image for what i need
[image: datatable remove]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try below and it success solve my issue

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Create a variable to store the DataTable instance
    var table;

    $('#PrintServer-select').change(function () {
        var printserverId = $(this).val();
        if (printserverId) {
            console.log(printserverId);
            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { printserverId: printserverId },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#branch-select').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $('#branch-select').append($('<option>', {
                            value: item.branchId,
                            text: item.vBranchDesc
                        }));
                    });

                    // Destroy the existing DataTable instance if it exists
                    if (table && $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
                        table.destroy();
                    }

                    // Hide the table using jQuery
                    $('#example').hide();

                    // Reinitialize the DataTable
                    table = $('#example').DataTable({
                        paging: false
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Initialize the DataTable outside of the change event
    table = $("#example").DataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "paging": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "columnDefs": [
            { className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10", "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
        ],
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 50, 100, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "pageLength": 10 // Set the default page length to 10
    });

    // Optional: Destroy the DataTable instance on document unload to prevent memory leaks
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        if (table && $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#example')) {
            table.destroy();
        }
    });
});
```

Aside from the fact that you can't consistently spell "destroy" between two different calls, and the fact that you're trying to call that method directly on the jQuery object rather than calling it properly as shown

Even five minutes walking through your code with the debugger would have shown you that you:

1-Create the table

2- Immediately try to destroy the table, but fail because you've not called the method correctly

3-Create the table

4- Create the table again

5-Immediately try to destroy the table, but fail because you've not called the method correctly, and this time you can't even spell it properly

And between all of that, you're not making any changes to the table at all, so the repeated calls to create and destroy it make absolutely no sense.